# Inconsistency in memcached due to MySQL master slave syncing delay

Tags: mysql, caching, memcached, cache-invalidation

We have recently switched to MySQL master/slave architecture. We do all writes and critical reads to master and all read to the slave machines. The master/slave architecture is designed as follows.

[image]

**Now, if we cache data read from slave machines may have chances to create stale objects in Memcached due to delay in master => slave synching.**

Temporarily, we have solved this problem by adding 5 min expiry while creating objects in Memcached. Assuming syncing will be done within 5 min. Now, even this 5 min delay is not acceptable to us.

Another way of solving this problem could be like Facebook solved by changing MySQL parser and carrying keys to the slave machine.

**Is there any other way of solving this problem?**

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. Are you using MySQL replication or is there some kind of custom data sync operation at work?

Comment: We are using MySQL replication